# Prioritize based on Column Value and select row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to give priority on Multiple columns and select row based on priority

I wanted to select ID's with RC priority in Category Column and Pending Priority in Status column and select Rows accordingly

Example: Input Dataframe

```
ID  Category      Status    Date
1   GC       Pending    01-03-2015
1   RC       Resolved   05-10-2016
1   GC       Resolved   06-03-2017
2   RC       Pending    09-08-2016
2   RC       Resolved   10-05-2014
3   GC       Resolved   10-08-2018
3   RC       Pending    13-05-2019
4   GC       Pending    10-06-2018
4   GC       Resolved   15-09-2014
```

Output Dataframe

```
ID  Category      Status    Date
1   RC       Resolved   05-10-2016
2   RC       Pending    09-08-2016
3   RC       Pending    13-05-2019
4   GC       Pending    10-06-2018
```

Comment: The output contains a category "GC" and a status "Resolved", is it expected ?  Else maybe something like: `df[(df['Category']=="RC") & (df['Status']=="Pending")]`

Comment: No....We need GC Category if RC Category is not Available against ID, Example for ID 4 we have GC because RC Category not available

Comment: There is some problem with my solution?

Comment: If I Wanted to give priority on Date like oldest date as high priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert columns to ordered categoricals with set priority by passing list to `categories` parameter, then sorting by 3 columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last remove duplicates with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['Category'] = pd.Categorical(df['Category'], ordered=True, categories=['GC','RC'])
df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'], ordered=True, categories=['Resolved','Pending'])

df = df.sort_values(['ID','Category','Status']).drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
print (df)
   ID Category    Status        Date
1   1       RC  Resolved  05-10-2016
3   2       RC   Pending  09-08-2016
6   3       RC   Pending  13-05-2019
7   4       GC   Pending  10-06-2018
```

Comment: So @jezrael here once defined as categorical, when you call `sort_values`, they are sorted according to the `categories` argument in `pd.Categorical`?

Comment: @yatu - I hope so. :)

Comment: @yatu - Also is important order in `df.sort_values(['ID','Category','Status'])` - it prioritize `Category` before `Status`

Comment: Ah this is neat. Yess, however the values in `Category` col now are not sorted alphabetically but rather according to the args in `pd.Categorical` right? Otherwise it'd be lexicographic

Comment: @yatu - Exactly.